# Python While Loop Admin-Server

Tags: python

Well i am doing an exercise which you have A server, an Admin and the clients.Admin should show the IP and the Port of the client.
I made all of them.But i got a problem at the Admin with the loop.As u see with the code below i made an infinity loop.If 3 clients are online i am gonna recieve only the one of them's IP and Port.Instead of One i need to get all the ip and port that are online on the server.But for some reason this doesnt work.

```
players = a.recv(80).decode()
print("Current players playing " + players)

x = 1
while True:
   client_list = a.recv(80).decode()
   print(client_list)
   x += 1
   input()
```

But if i make a loop like this

```
for players in range(0, 3):
   client_list = a.recv(80).decode()
   print(client_list)
   input()
```

then this works but for only 3 times.I dont have idea what i am doing wrong.
Thanks for your time.

```
CLIENT CODE
    import socket

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4000))

helloMSG = ("Hello\r\n")
s.send(helloMSG.encode())

greetings = s.recv(80).decode()
print(greetings)

gameMSG = ("Game\r\n")
s.send(gameMSG.encode())

readyMSG = s.recv(80).decode()

running = 1

while running:

    guess = input("My guess is:")

    guessstring = "My Guess is: " + str(guess) + "\r\n"

    s.send(guessstring.encode())

    result = s.recv(80).decode()

    print(result)

    if (result == "Correct\r\n"):
        running = 0

s.close()
```

AND THE ADMIN CODE `

```
import socket

a = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
a.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4001))

print("connected!\n")

message = "Hello\r\n"
a.send(message.encode())

result = a.recv(80).decode()
print(result)

message = "Who\r\n"
a.send(message.encode())


players = a.recv(80).decode()
print("Current players playing " + players)

x = 1
while True:
client_list = a.recv(80).decode()
print(client_list)
x += 1
input()
```

Comment: `a.recv()` should be a blocking function so you shouldn't need the also-blocking function `input()`

Comment: how can i do it without the a.recv()? i need it to recieve the data.I also put the input() cause if i didnt the whole thing bugs and dont display the ip

Comment: Please provide the client code and the admin code. In this way it will be easy to provide the solution

Comment: ok i am do it now